# Salesforce Knowledge - display latest version only

Tags: knowledge, salesforce1-platform

When creating a salesforce knowledge article, when we click on version, we see the first created version. Now I edit the 1st version with some changes and publish it.So, now If I click on versions tab I see two records, version number 2 and version number 1. What should I do, so that I see only the latest version, when I click on Versions tab, I just want the latest version visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default Knowledge record layout, the Details tab will always display the latest version.[image]

The purpose of the Version tab is to provide a record history.